# unable to parse xml data

Tags: php, xml

i am unable to parse xml document .
well my task was like that

i got xml page from curl which contain ip info

```
<ip_address>209.59.194.20</ip_address><ip_type>Mapped</ip_type><Network><organization>thoughtconvergence.com</organization><carrier>whidbey internet services</carrier><asn>6295</asn><connection_type/><line_speed/><ip_routing_type>fixed</ip_routing_type><Domain><tld>com</tld><sld>trafficz</sld></Domain></Network><Location><continent>north america</continent><latitude>34.03708</latitude><longitude>-118.42789</longitude><CountryData><country>united states</country><country_code>us</country_code><country_cf>99</country_cf></CountryData><region>southwest</region><StateData><state>california</state><state_code>ca</state_code><state_cf>80</state_cf></StateData><dma>803</dma><msa>31100</msa><CityData><city>los angeles</city><postal_code>90064</postal_code><time_zone>-8</time_zone><area_code>323</area_code><city_cf>61</city_cf></CityData></Location></ipinfo>
```

i try to parse it

```
$book = simplexml_load_string($datax);
$ipadd = $book->ip_address;  
$ipatype = $book->ip_type;  
$ip_routing_type = $book->Network->ip_routing_type;  
$state = $book->Location->StateData->state;
$country = $book->Location->CountryData->country;
$continent = $book->Location->continent;   
$region = $book->Location->region;
```

now am getting few errors
1) Entity: line 2: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document
2 Trying to get property of non-object in line #

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your XML is invalid. It has a closing tag for a root element at the end of the data

```
</ipinfo>
```

but there is no header tag. If you tack:

```
<ipinfo>
```

to the front of it I'll bet it will work.